# Why ID column empty when creating external table with ID used in partitioning?

Tags: parquet, azure-data-explorer

I use the following KQL request to create an external table in Azure Data Explorer:

```
.create external table TESTS (ID: string, Key: string, Value: string)
kind=adl
dataformat=parquet
(
    h@'abfss://gold@dev.dfs.core.windows.net/db/1/ID=X;impersonate',
    h@'abfss://gold@dev.dfs.core.windows.net/db/1/ID=Y;impersonate'
)
```

External table is well created, but values in column "ID" are empty, why ?

It works if I create a column "ID2" and reference it in path above, but not sure if it is the best solution.

Comment: What is your input data? in the parquet file

Comment: I found the solution, I changed the kind to delta. Because parquet file comes from delta table creation

Answer (score 0):

Also you can try with below approach as well to achieve your requirement. In this a `parquet` file is stored in Azure storage and the data has been retrieved successfully.

> External table is well created, but values in column "ID" are empty, why ?

The external `table` is empty even after it is created, because as `abfss` refers to **`Data Lake Storage Gen2`**, a `Hierarchical Namespace` must be enabled while creating the storage account as shown below.
[image]

After enabling it, data is shown successfully after creating the table, as you can see in the output below.

```sql
.create external table ['<table name>'] (['ID']:long,['Name']:string,['Age']:long)
    kind = adl
    dataformat = parquet
    (
          h@'abfss://firstcont@newst6391.dfs.core.windows.net;impersonate'
    )
```

Execute the table.

```sql
external_table('<table name>')
| take 10
```

**Output:**

[image]